# How to combine Legacy DB2 records containing XML into new XML column

Tags: xml, db2

I have a DB2 table that has xml stored in it broken across multiple rows as char(254). Each row is not necessarily valid XML, but all of the rows together do make a valid document. We currently pull all the records into our Java application, build an XML Document and then do various things with it.

I would like to take the existing data from the existing table and combine it into one record (per key) in a new table using the XML data type so that I can use some of the newer xml query features.

I've started by just creating a select statement that will return the data I need using XMLAGG(XMLTEXT(column)) but this escapes the xml nodes that are already in the column. When I then try an insert with the results of this select statement, I get a SQLCODE 20345 invalid XML.

I could of course pull this into java and unescape it, but I want to do it all in a select insert statement due to the number of records involved.

It seems like there should already be a way to do this, but I'm not finding it.

We are on DB2 version 11 and LISTAGG is not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think XMLTEXT is doing something else than what you need. I think it is used to construct an XML text node in an XML document. If I understand you correctly you'd like to build a query that concatenates several char rows into a single text value and then convert that to an XML document. You should be able to do this using XMLPARSE() with specifying XML as target type like so:

```
SELECT 
    XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('string(/a/b/@foo)' PASSING X) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
FROM (
    SELECT xmlparse('<a><b foo="bar"/><c/></a>')
    FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
) AS X(X)
```

For more info check out:
[How to convert xml text stored in a VARCHAR and select using XQUERY expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922606/how-to-convert-xml-text-stored-in-a-varchar-and-select-using-xquery-expression)