# How to convert xml text stored in a VARCHAR and select using XQUERY expression

Tags: sql, db2

I have xml documents stored as text in a VARCHAR column. I'd like to convert the text to XML documents in order to perform XQUERY selects on the documents.

An example document looks like:

```
<a>
   <b foor="bar"/>
   <c/>
</a>
```

My query looks like:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY('//c' PASSING 
  XMLCAST('<a><b foor="bar"/><c/></a>' AS XML)) 
FROM SYSIBM.sysdummy1
```

But instead of returning a  element I get the following error message:

> SQL Error [10507]: The Context item in an axis step must be a node. SQLCODE=-16012, SQLSTATE=10507

How can I get this to work?

===========================================
**Update #1:**
Just in case anyone stumbles upon the same problem. At least in my environment the queries below work but instead of returning the text of the matching xml nodes I only got columns showing up as value "[le]". I had to cast the result to e.g. VARCHAR XMLCAST() to get the xml as text. So I changed Stavr00's query to:

```
SELECT 
    XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('string(/a/b/@foo)' PASSING X) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
FROM (
SELECT xmlparse('<a><b foo="bar"/><c/></a>')
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
) AS X(X)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @data_henrik.  However I recommend using CTE nesting as to parse XML only once:

```
SELECT 
    XMLQUERY('string(/a/b/@foo)' PASSING X) 
   ,XMLQUERY('//c' PASSING X)
FROM (
SELECT xmlparse('<a><b foo="bar"/><c/></a>')
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
) AS X(X)
```

Comment: @data_henrik Do you have any idea why XMLCAST gives me the attribute text for the first XMLQUERY (/a/b/@foo) but just an empty string for the second one (//c). Does it have something to do with the first one getting an attribute and the second one an element? Is it correct to cast the returned results using XMLCAST()? Otherwise I don't get at the text values...

Answer (score 2):

Not syntax-tested below, but I recommend to use [XMLPARSE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022191.html). It converts the string into XML which can be used by XMLQUERY:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY('//c' PASSING 
        xmlparse(document '<a><b foor="bar"/><c/></a>'))
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

That should return `<c/>`.